# how to set previous next icons in middle of height of image on hover that image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I was doing previous and next experiments like facebook, as we do a hover on image it will show previous and next icons. I modified the icons a little bit using simple CSS. but only thing i am missing here is the correct position of the navigation div's.
I want them in the middle of image no matter if the image is 600*600 or 1024*800.

i tried these, but didnt make any progress -

```
var maskHeight = ($('mainOne').height() - 50);
$('#hoverP').css({top:maskHeight}).show();
$('#hoverN').css({top:maskHeight}).show();
```

here is sample test case, which includes everything related to problem, Please Help.-

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="./jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .imgHover {
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
        }
        .imgHover .hoverP {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 3px;
            top:-200px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .imgHover .hoverN {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            top:-200px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .prev_big,.next_big {
            background-color:rgba(66,28,82,0.4);;
            border:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
            color:#FFF;
            font-size:78px;
            font-weight:700;
            width:30px;
            height:200px;
            line-height:200px;
            -webkit-transition:.4s all;
            -moz-transition:.4s all;
            -o-transition:.4s all;
            transition:.4s all;
            text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
            z-index:3;
            text-decoration:none;
            -moz-transition-duration:.4s;
            -webkit-transition-duration:.4s;
            -o-transition-duration:.4s;
            transition-duration:.4s;
        }

        .prev_big {
            border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
            border-top-right-radius:15px;
            margin-left:-3px;
            padding:0 20px 0 0;
        }

        .next_big {
            border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
            border-top-left-radius:15px;
            right:0;
            padding:0 5px 0 15px;
        }

        .prev_big:hover,.next_big:hover {
            color:#FFF;
            background:#732C7B;
            padding-top:140px;
            padding-bottom:140px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".imgHover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.95).end().children(".hoverP").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hoverP").hide();
        }
    );
    $(".imgHover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.95).end().children(".hoverN").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hoverN").hide();
        }
    );
});
</script>
<body>

    <div class="imgHover">
        <div class="hoverP"><a class="prev_big" href="page1.html" title="View Previous Page"><</a></div>
            <img id="mainOne" src="./oneB.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="hoverN"><a class="next_big" href="page3.html" title="View --Next-- Page">></a></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need jQuery, bunch of styles with filled markup? I've made this from complete scratch and you see if it's useful

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWdC/)

On the other hand you can use transitions for smoothness - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWdC/1/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
    <div class="bar"><a href="#">Previous</a><a href="#">Next</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bar {
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(25,25,25,.5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

div:hover .bar {
    opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper a {
    position: absolute;
}

.wrapper a:nth-of-type(1) {
    left: 0;
}

.wrapper a:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 0;
}
```